# What was Jong-goo's sin?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wailing

I just watched *The Wailing* yesterday, and near the end of the movie there is a dialog where

> Moo-myeong (the woman in white)

tells Jong-goo that the devil targeted him because he sinned, to which he replied something to the effect of "but she got sick first!". What exactly was his sin?

Comment: I had the same question. At first I thought it was adultery (the sex scene in the car at the beginning of the film). However, after re-watching it, I realized that was with his wife....so I am left with the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ref : [The Wailing Explained](https://www.thisisbarry.com/single-post/2018/05/21/Gokseong-Wailing-2016-Movie-Plot-Ending-Explained)

> He and his men throw the Stranger's body over the cliff and kill him.
> He commits a sin and Moo-myung, who watches on, loses the ability to
> protect his daughter.
>
> She also mentions about her trap and that it would work only if
> Jong-goo waits till three rooster crows before going home. She tells
> him that he has sinned by plotting to kill and killing and hence he
> must go through this test of faith.

Jong-goo willfully throws the stranger over the cliff intending to kill him. The Japanese stranger is not possessed at this moment in time... he's shown to be confused and running for his life. Jong-goo's sin is murder.. or the attempt to.

Jong-goo tries to justify that his daughter got really sick and hence he tried to kill the Japanese stranger to protect her. But regardless of the reason, the act still remains a sin.

Comment: How is it a Sin to kill the Devil? He is running for his life but that doesn't change the fact that he is a devil.

Comment: The man they are attacking at that point is not possessed by the devil. He's an innocent man fearing for his life and on the run.